# Simple Applet question : About jar dependency

Tags: java, security, applet, jnlp

I am developing a small applet appliaction using JNLP. I have total 3 jar's. one is main and 2 are supporting. using few classes from supporting into main jar. So my question is,
1) Do i need to mention all 3 jar's in jnlp file ?
2) Do i need to sign all these 3 jar's ?

Right now I am mentioning only main jar in resources tag of JNLP. Also supporting jars are not signed as well.

When I run my applet it is working fine. but gives lots of messages in java console as follows,

JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass.....try again..

for almost all the classes in main jar

Any help on this much appreciated !!!

Thanks In Advance .

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp href="mt_test.jnlp" codebase="/mic/ri/lib/">
  <information>
     <title>test</title>
     <vendor>test</vendor>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se href="java.sun.com/products/autod/j2se"version="1.6+"/…;
    <jar href="jmy.jar" main="true" version="0007.0000.0012.0000" download="eager"/>
    <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>
  </resources>
  <applet-desc name="MIC"main class="com.test.test.JApplet" width="300" height="300">
  </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Is this valid jnlp ?

Comment: Your question is very confusing, so all I can recommend is to validate the launch file using JaNeLA (http://pscode.org/janela/).  BTW Does "using few classes from supporting into main jar." mean those classes have been **put** into the main Jar, or the main Jar requires them to be on the run-time class-path? 1) depends whether classes from the support jar are used in the applet, if yes, then YES. 2) No.  Signing Jars has nothing to do with class-loading.

Comment: Hi Andrew .. sorry for not putting question clearly. Yes main jar requires other jars at compile time as well as at run time i.e in classpath.  I am not finding JNLP2ClassLoader in my classpath, Do i need any external lib for it ? What is the use of this JNLP2ClassLoader ?

Comment: '<? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jnlp  href="mt_test.jnlp" codebase="/mic/ri/lib/">
<information><title>test</title><vendor>test</vendor>
</information><security><all-permissions/></security>     
<resources>
<j2se href="http://java.sun.com/products/autod/j2se"version="1.6+"/>
<jar href="jmy.jar" main="true" version="0007.0000.0012.0000" download="eager"/><property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/></resources><applet-desc name="MIC"main class="com.test.test.JApplet" width="300" height="300"></applet-desc></jnlp>'Is this valid jnlp ?

Comment: I put your code into the question (you could have done this, too - there is an edit link there), but I still don't really understand your problem. Does it work without the messages when you mention all your jars there?   (The JNLP2ClassLoader supposedly is part of the implementation of your plugin.) Additionally, a copy of those messages could help.

Comment: You need to list all the jars you're using and you also have to sign them all if you don't want any warnings.

Comment: @biziclop I have tried adding all the signed jars but still the "try again" messages are coming.

Comment: @Paulo messages in java console as follows,basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.package.MyApplet$1:try again.
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Removed progress listener: null
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.package.DefaultMyLookAndFeel: try again ..
try again .. messages are coming for all the other classes as well.